# specify param in R plumber

Tags: r, rest, api, plumber

I created a REST API in R using plumber.

```
#* description
#* @param id Unique ID  
#* @get /data/<id:int>
```

where id is required to be numeric. However, plumber also sets `required = true`. How can I set type of id to numeric (integer) without setting required to true? Cannot find any hints in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#* description
#* @param id:int Unique ID  
#* @get /data
function(id=NULL) {}
```

Source:

[Is there a way to add optional parameter in API using R Plumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63496535/is-there-a-way-to-add-optional-parameter-in-api-using-r-plumber)

https://www.shirin-glander.de/2018/01/plumber/

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see a generic definition of the function for this endpoint. Not wanting `id` to be required indicates the desire to allow the function to work without a param. To accomplish this, you could define a second endpoint that contains only the root part of the dynamic path:

```r
library(plumber)

#* Simple ID endpoint
#* @param id Unique ID
#* @get /data/<id:int>
function(id) {
  list(
    id = id,
    type = typeof(id)
  )
}

#* Data endpoint
#* @get /data
function() {
  list("Data endpoint")
}
```

Given this, requests to `/data/<id>` will return information based on `id`, while requests to `/data` can return something else entirely.