# Is there a way to add optional parameter in API using R Plumber?

Tags: r, api, plumber

I have this routing that I'm trying to make it work:

```
#* @get /outcomes-aggregate/<categoryId:int>/<classId>/<perspectiveID>/<sn>
#* @serializer unboxedJSON
function(res, req, categoryId, classId,sn=NULL){
  
  ## initialization
  query <- NULL
  data_to_send <- list()
  ...
}
```

This `api` is supposed to take the request with optional `sn` value. However, this is not working. The `sn` value may or may not exist and the query is ran based on this value. But when I run it, I keep getting this error:

```
call: http://localhost:3982/outcomes-aggregated/1/342342

0   "404 - Resource Not Found"
```

It only works if I also include the `sn`.

```
call: http://localhost:3982/outcomes-aggregated/1/342342/NULL
```

How can I make this parameter optional? Or will I have to create another function without this value?

**Update**

I updated the routing and the logic to attempt to correct for this issue.

```
#* @get /outcomes-aggregate/<categoryId:int>/<classId>/<sn>
#* @serializer unboxedJSON
function(res, req, categoryId, classId,sn=NULL){
  
  ## initialization
  query <- NULL
  data_to_send <- list()
  ...

   if(missing(sn) || pracma::strcmp(sn, "NULL")){
    query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM classes WHERE classID = '", classId, "'")
  } else{
    query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM classes WHERE classID = '", classId, "' and sn = '", sn , "'")
  }
  ...

}
```

This is working for now but I have to still add `NULL` in the url. I'd love to hear a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on @BrunoTremblay's response, I ended up converting function to use query instead of path. This worked fine.

The new function looks like this:

```
#* @get /outcomes-aggregate <-- remove the path
#* @serializer unboxedJSON
function(res, req, categoryId, classId,sn=NULL){
  
  ## initialization
  query <- NULL
  data_to_send <- list()
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path has three parameters and you are only providing 2. It works when you provided a third one but it is not mapped to sn. It is mapped to perspectiveID.

/outcomes-aggregate/categoryId:int//

Comment: that's helpful. So, it has to have the same name as listed in the api. But is there a way to make it optional so that it can take either 2 or 3 parameters?

Comment: I've updated the question based on what you said about the parameters. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Not for path parameters, it can be optional for query parameter http://localhost:3982/outcomes-aggregated/1/342342?sn=NULL